# OpenStack Instance connect with External internet

Tags: networking, cloud, openstack

So I created an openstack instance using an image I made in Virtual box. The OS (CentOs7) is working as expected. The only issue I am having is that it cannot connect to the internet or an external network.

The users need to use the internet for testing the databases and to get their software.

I am sure there is something I did not set up properly in Openstack. I am not really able to pinpoint what that issue is because I am not really sure where to start. I did not configure the network when I set up this image.

I also can't figure out how to access the console openstack (like a terminal). I have been trying to do this in the dashboard. I am on a windows machine.

Any help or direction to where to find my answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check your openstack router settings. You can do this from Horizon Dashboard or from CLI.

Make sure that gateway is set appropriately in the router configuration. Also ensure you are able to ping this gateway !!